# Tagging functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

An elementary Haskell question:

I would like to "tag functions" in Haskell: I have a list

```
  scheme = [ f1, f2, f3, ... ]
```

which is built from some simple functions, some of them belonging to a certain group:

```
  f1 :: a -> a
  f1 a = ...
  f2 :: a -> a -- "belongs to group"
  f2 a = ...
  f3 :: a -> a
  f3 a = ...
  f4 :: a -> a -- "belongs to group"
  f4 a = ...
  ...
```

I want to create a smaller list, containing only the functions belonging to that subgroup:

```
  filter belongsToGroup scheme
```

In Java, the functions would be subclasses of a Function class, some of them implementing an empty tagging interface FunctionGroup. The filter function could then be realized with the operator `instanceof`

I tried to understand how I could mimic this behaviour in Haskell (studying "type classes"), but had no success.

Any help?

Comment: Type classes are not useful for that. I don't think it's possible in Haskell in the same way it's possible in Java. If you want to group functions, your best bet is to lug around pairs (function-group, function).

Comment: With concrete details of the problem you are working on, we can likely give design suggestions that will be both native Haskell and more useful to you.

Comment: Greg's right; there's probably a much more Haskellish way of doing what you want to do, which could simplify your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One approach to this problem would be to create a data type representing these functions.

```
data TaggedFunction a = UsefulFunction (a -> a)
                      | UselessFunction (a -> a)

f1 :: TaggedFunction a
f1 = UsefulFunction $ \x -> x

f2 :: TaggedFunction a
f2 = UselessFunction $ \x -> x

isUseful :: TaggedFunction a -> Bool
isUseful (UsefulFunction _) = True
isUseful _                  = False

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let fs = [f1, f2, f1, f2]
        useful = filter isUseful fs
        print $ (_f $ head useful) 4
```

This method is easily expandable to include more than two groups, and could even be automatically generated with e.g. Template Haskell.

#### Edit

After a bit of playing around, I like this refactor of `TaggedFunction` better.

```
data TaggedFunction a = Group1 { _f :: a }
                      | Group2 { _f :: a }
                      | Group3 { _f :: a }

f1 :: TaggedFunction (a -> a)
f1 = Group1 $ \x -> x

f2 :: TaggedFunction (a -> a)
f2 = Group2 $ \x -> x

isGroup :: Int -> TaggedFunction a -> Bool
isGroup 1 (Group1 _) = True
isGroup 2 (Group2 _) = True
isGroup 3 (Group3 _) = True
isGroup _ _          = False

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let fs = [f1, f2, f1, f2]
        useful = filter (isGroup 1) fs
    print $ length useful
    print $ (_f $ head useful) 4
```

Output:

```
λ> main
2
4
```

Note that `isGroup` is now not total (which I don't like), but it was more convenient than individual `isGroupN` functions for the purposes of this example.

Comment: Elliot, I liked this approach and tried to implement it in my example. However, after making my function an instance of a new type `Condition ( [a] -> a )`, I am unable to apply it. In this script http://ideone.com/TpEc8O it fails in line 27 where I want to apply the function...

Comment: Can't say this was 100% what you were going for, [but it does work](http://ideone.com/2rJO9C). Primary changes are some type signatures (which helped me to debug), moving `[a] -> a` into the Condition type signature (per my second example), and the addition of an unpacking function `apply` to actually run the function held in a Condition.

Comment: Thank you, Elliot - it works! So it seems the main point was to use record syntax `{ apply :: a }` with a member named 'apply' - a good name which also improves readability of the `compute` function. But I still wonder how to access the parts of a data declaration when _not_ using the record syntax (very basic, I know... but it puzzles me).

Comment: The next best thing, IMHO, would be to write an accessor using the Lens library. This would allow something along the lines of `f^.apply x`. You could also write a function of the same type as apply without using the record syntax. The main problem is that there are multiple data constructors, so you need some manner of pattern matching. Record syntax just happens to be the cleanest method for this case.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell actively discourages you from using type system escape hatches. (An `instanceof`-like construct would break some nice type system properties such as parametricity.) You most likely want to use this type:

```
type TaggedFunction a b = (a -> b, Bool)
```

Where first component is just the regular function you want to use, and the second component is `True` when the function belongs to the group, or `False` otherwise.

Then you filter `TaggedFunction`s like this: `filter snd tfs`

Comment: I suppose you could combine our two techniques and pass around `type TaggedFunction a b = (a -> b, Tag)`, where `data Tag = Group1 | Group2 | Group3`.

Comment: @ElliotRobinson: Indeed. Your answer is great. (better than mine IMO) :-)

Comment: Thanks! Just goes to show there's more than one way to peel an orange. I dig neglect to include your warning against subverting the type system.

Comment: Elliot's suggestion is an excellent demonstration of type algebra: the type `Either a a` is isomorphic to `(a, Maybe ())`. (Well, except for non-termination, as always...) In this case, `TaggedFunction a b` can be modeled as either `Either (a -> b) (Either (a -> b) (a -> b))` (either `Left f`, `Right (Left f)` or `Right (Right f)`), or as `(a -> b, Maybe (Maybe ()))` (either `(f, Nothing)`, `(f, Just Nothing)` or `(f, Just (Just ()))`).

Comment: @LuisCasillas: I am aware of the equational theory for bicartesian closed categories. :-)